# NSRangeException in cellForRowAtIndexPath with array as data

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I'm using a UITableView and an NSMutableArray for keeping tracks of the data. In some rare cases I get an NSRangeException in heightForRowAtIndexPath even though numberOfRowsInSection is using the same array eg:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _listSearchResults.count;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *data = [_listSearchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    bool isBanner = (bool) [data objectForKey:@"isBanner"];
    if(isBanner)
    {
        return 160;
    }
    else
    {
        return 44;
    }
}
```

Sometimes _listSearchResults gets modified after numberOfRowsInSection has been call (due to async calls and large data sets) but before heightForRowAtIndexPath!
Do you have any suggestions to "lock" the array. Is this the right design pattern?

**Update**: I think the problem is that a have multiple ways of updating the tableView thus reloading the data. When I scroll the tableView, it can fetch more items, but I can also filter the table cells (thus making new calls to the server).

Regards.

Comment: You should call reloadData after modified `_listSearchResults`

Comment: Loading the data calls numberOfRowsInSection and then heightForRowAtIndexPath, so _listSearchResults should match. But they sometime (rare) doesnt.

Comment: @Nam there is a chance that the array is modified between the calls of numberOfRowsInSection and heightForRowAtIndexPath as you mentioned it is a async calls. My suggestion is to reload data only after the completion of the async calls.

Comment: @Nam "But they sometime (rare) doesnt". When?

Comment: Unfortunately I dont know when. My only guess is that the two async calls to update the tableView conflict.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that cellForRowAtIndexPath has old data. The reason may be that you are calling reload at the starting and then again when the data returns,so basically you might be calling second reload before the completion of first reload, so it might cause cellForRowAtIndexPath to behave unexpectedly.

You can do one thing try setting datasource to `nil` when you fetch new data that way cellForRowAtIndexPath will not be executed, and set it to `self`  when the async returns data and reload the table.

Like this

```
self.tableView.dataSource = nil
```

and

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self
```

Comment: Setting data source to nil seems to empty the tableView UI and doesnt work for getting more results when scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Only change dataSource on the main thread. Do your server call in the background. When it finishes calculate what you want the new dataSource to be, and then you set dataSource on the main thread. Together with a call to reload the table view.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in the crash reports, that all devices had low memory so I will try and have tried to do some memory leak analysis and clean up.

Thank you all for your suggestions.

Comment: Similarly, I had this issue due to a retain cycle between my service class that was fetching the data from the server and my view model class that was calling the service (within the service completion block).